# PyCharm not seeing PyYAML with Pipenv

Tags: python, pycharm, pyyaml

I'm struggling to get PyCharm to see PyYAML (`import yaml`).

I tried both:

- installing `PyYAML` through terminal `pipenv install pyyaml` or
- installing it through PyCharm itself.

Both produce the same effect - it's listed in the modules ok but PyCharm still underlines it with a red line and tells me I need to import it.

To make things even more confusing:

- When running the app outside PyCharm, Pipenv sees PyYAML ok.
- When running the app inside PyCharm but with another virtual env manger (ie not Pipenv) it also sees PyYAML ok.

So it seems it's specifically a PyCharm + Pipenv issue?

Anyone ran into this issue? Any advice?

Comment: check python interpreter in PyCharm settings and see if PyYAML is listed in installed packages.

Comment: Yep, listed there all good. Tried deleting & reinstalling - exactly same effect. In fact, when it's underlined in red I can click "install package PyYAML" infinitely many times and every time as if nothing happened